# Marshalling not working: In case of nested Dto

Tags: java, serialization, xml-serialization, xstream

I am saving my configration details in an xml file its structure is somewat like this

```
<A>
    <b>
        <name>xxxxx</name>
        <age>xxxxx</age>
        <c>
          <someFeilds>yyyy</someFeilds>
        </c>
        <c>
          <someFeilds>yyyy</someFeilds>
        </c>
        <c>
          <someFeilds>yyyy</someFeilds>
        </c>
    </b>
    <b>
        <name>xxxxx</name>
        <age>xxxxx</age>
        <c>
            <someFeilds>yyyy</someFeilds>
        </c>
    </b>
</A>
```

I am able to marshal it to my DTO `A` whoes structure is

```
class A {
    public ArrayList<B> bdtoInst;
}
class B {
    public String name;
    public String age;
    public ArrayList<C> cdtoInst;
}
class C {
    public String someFeilds;
}
```

Xstream declartion is

```
    XStream xStream = new XStream();
    xStream.alias("A", A.class);
    xStream.addImplicitCollection(A.class, "bdtoInst");
    xStream.alias("b", B.class);
    xStream.addImplicitCollection(B.class, "cdtoInst");
    xStream.alias("c", C.class);
```

I am able to marshal it to my DTO, but when i unmarshal it, i am not getting the correct format, it is coming like this:

```
<A>
    <b>
        <name>xxxxx</name>
        <age>xxxxx</age>
        <c>
            <someFeilds>yyyy</someFeilds>
        </c>
        <c>
            <someFeilds>yyyy</someFeilds>
        </c>
        <c>
            <someFeilds>yyyy</someFeilds>
        </c>
        <c>
            <someFeilds>yyyy</someFeilds>
        </c>
    </b>
    <b>
        <name>xxxxx</name>
        <age>xxxxx</age>
        <c reference="../../b/c"/>
    </b>
</A>
```

I am using **xstream-1.4.3.jar.**

Comment: I am getting <c reference="../../b/c"/> because of  XPATH_RELATIVE_REFERENCES used in the xstream link:http://xstream.codehaus.org/graphs.html, but i ma unable to understand why all <someFeilds .../> are coming into first node.

Comment: The `C`-class has only one string variable, but you are supplying multiple values to it.

Comment: Yes, my mistake i have made the changes above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of XPATH_RELATIVE_REFERENCES used in the xstream link:xstream.codehaus.org/graphs.html
in the xstream declaration we have to add

```
  xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
```

than instead of marking the refrence value will be placed.